Training LSTM Model with StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset using DJL
This is my first experimentation in training models and DJL. I am trying to use the Stanford QA dataset to train the LSTM Model using DJL.
Below is the configuration of the trainset dataset. The batchsize is 1024
StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset trainDataset = StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset.builder()
        .setSampling(batchSize, false)
        .optUsage(Dataset.Usage.TRAIN)
        .optDataBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0f))
        .optLabelBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0f))
        .optManager(NDManager.newBaseManager(arguments.getEngine())).build();
trainDataset.prepare(new ProgressBar());

The following is the getData() method:
Iterator<Batch> batchIter = trainDataset.getData(NDManager.newBaseManager(arguments.getEngine())).iterator();

It returns the following shape information for 2 batches.

titleShape, contextShape, questionShape shape: (1024, 3), (1024, 416), (1024, 29)

Label shape: (1024, 19)

titleShape, contextShape, questionShape shape: (1024, 13), (1024, 430), (1024, 34)

Label shape: (1024, 19)


Using the above values what should be the Shape configuration to initialize the Trainer object?
trainer.initialize(new Shape(new long[] { ??, ??, ??}));

And what parameters shuld be passed into the addSingleton method in the below model configuration:
private static Block getLSTMModel() {
    SequentialBlock block = new SequentialBlock();

    block.addSingleton(input -> {
        Shape inputShape = input.getShape();
        long batchSize = inputShape.get(0);
        long channel = inputShape.get(2);
        long time = inputShape.size() / (batchSize * channel);
        NDArray arr = input.reshape(new Shape(new long[] { batchSize, time, channel }));
        return arr;
    });

    block.add(new LSTM.Builder().setStateSize(1092).setNumLayers(4)
            .build());
    block.add(BatchNorm.builder().optEpsilon(1e-5f).optMomentum(0.9f).build());
    block.add(Blocks.batchFlattenBlock());
    block.add(Linear.builder().setUnits(128).build());
    return block;
}

